# SSD caching + HDD VS SSD alone for OS?

Tags: ssd

I got a new "Gigabyte Z68X-UD4-B3" motherboard which supports SSD caching. I also have an old OCZ Vertex 60GB SSD and a WD Caviar Black(1T) HDD.

I am thinking of installing the OS to the HDD and using the SSD for caching. How would the performance in this setup compare with having the OS on the SSD?

Comment: Have you searched before? Performance questions regarding SSDs/HDDs and operating systems have been asked and answered several times.

Comment: I am not just comparing SSD and HDD. The motherboard support SSD caching, hence I want to know how the performance is compare to a dedicated SSD. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen Anand's review of the Z68 chipset? It covers this, and the result is that you're better off dedicating an SSD to OS/Apps duty if it's large enough, but SRT is better than nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel Smart Response vs SSD as primary drive](http://superuser.com/questions/384934/intel-smart-response-vs-ssd-as-primary-drive)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance of Intel's Smart Response Technology (SRT) on Z68 Sandy Bridge motherboards has been examined by [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4329/intel-z68-chipset-smart-response-technology-ssd-caching-review/8):

> it's not going to make your high end SSD obsolete. You'll still get
>   better overall performance by grabbing a large (80-160GB+) SSD,
>   putting your OS + applications on it, and manually moving all of your
>   large media files to a separate hard drive. What SRT does offer
>   however is a stepping stone to a full blown SSD + HDD setup and a
>   solution that doesn't require end user management.

In other words, by using SSD caching rather than separating the SSD and HDD, you trade a bit of performance consistency for convenience and simplicity for the user.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to have a look at the AnandTech review.